# Create reverse complement sequence based on AWK

Tags: python, awk

Dear stackoverflow users,

I have **TAB** sep data like this:

```
head -4 input.tsv

seq A      C change
seq T      A ok
seq C      C change
seq AC   CCT change
```

And I need create reverse complement function in awk which do something like this

```
head -4 output.tsv

seq T      G change
seq T      A ok
seq G      G change
seq GT   AGG change
```

So if 4th column is flagged "change" I need to create reverse complement sequence.

HINT - the same things doing for example `tr` in bash - **Bash one liner for this task is:**

```
echo "ACCGA" | rev | tr "ATGC" "TACG"
```

I was tried something like this

```
awk 'BEGIN {c["A"] = "T"; c["C"] = "G"; c["G"] = "C"; c["T"] = "A" }{OFS="\t"}
function revcomp(   i, o) {
    o = ""
    for(i = length; i > 0; i--)
        o = o c[substr($0, i, 1)]
    return(o)
}
{

if($4 == "change"){$2 = revcom(); $3 = revcom()} print $0; else print $0}' input
```

**Biological reverse sequence mean:**

```
A => T
C => G
G => C
T => A
```

**and reverse complement mean:**

```
ACCATG => CATGGT
```

Edited: Also anybody just for education can share this solution in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little *tinkering* of your attempt you can do something like below.

```
function revcomp(arg) {
    o = ""
    for(i = length(arg); i > 0; i--)
        o = o c[substr(arg, i, 1)]
    return(o)
}

BEGIN {c["A"] = "T"; c["C"] = "G"; c["G"] = "C"; c["T"] = "A" ; OFS="\t"}

{
    if($4 == "change") {
        $2 = revcomp($2); 
        $3 = revcomp($3)
    } 
}1
```

The key here was to use the function `revcomp` to take the arguments as the column values and operate on it by iterating from end. You were previously doing on the whole line `$0`, i.e. `substr($0, i, 1)` which would be causing a lot of unusual lookups on the array `c`.

I've also taken the liberty of changing the prototype of your function `revcomp` to take the input string and return the reversed one. Because I wasn't sure how you were intending to use in your original attempt.

If you are intending to use the above in a part of a larger script, I would recommend putting the whole code as-above in a script file, set the she-bang interpreter to `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` and run the script as `awk -f script.awk input.tsv`

A crude bash version implemented in `awk` would like below. Note that, it is not clean and not a *recommended* approach. See more at [AllAboutGetline](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline)

As before call the function as `$2 = revcomp_bash($2)` and `$3 = revcomp_bash($3)`

```
function revcomp_bash(arg) {
    o = ""
    cmd = "printf \"%s\" " arg "| rev | tr \"ATGC\" \"TACG\""
    while ( ( cmd | getline o ) > 0 ) { 

    }
    close(cmd);
    return(o)
}
```

Your whole code speaks GNU `awk`-ism, so didn't care for converting it to a POSIX compliant one. You could use `split()` with a empty de-limiter instead of `length()` but the POSIX specification gladly says that "The effect of a null string as the value of *fs* is unspecified."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe silly question, but I do not see any "awk" on the start of script?

Comment: @Geroge: Just use the whole snippet around `awk '...' input.tsv`

Comment: this is absolutely perfect solution and looks it works super! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Your code is POSIX compliant, no GNU-isms there. The one tweak you should consider making is that `revcomp(arg)` should be `revcomp(arg,    i,o)` so that `i` and `o` are function-local variables and so independent of their values elsewhere in the code or in a second invocation of that code. If you do that then you don't need `o = ""`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples(in GNU `awk`).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  label["A"]="T"
  label["C"]="G"
  label["G"]="C"
  label["T"]="A"
}
function cVal(field){
  delete array
  num=split($field,array,"")
  for(k=1;k<=num;k++){
   if(array[k] in label){
     val=label[array[k]] val
   }
  }
  $field=val
  val=""
}
$NF=="change"{
  for(i=2;i<=(NF-1);i++){
    cVal(i)
  }
}
1
'  Input_file | column -t
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                               ##Starting BEGIN section of this code here.
  label["A"]="T"                     ##Creating array label with index A and value T.
  label["C"]="G"                     ##Creating array label with index C and value G.
  label["G"]="C"                     ##Creating array label with index G and value C.
  label["T"]="A"                     ##Creating array label with index T and value A.
}
function cVal(field){                ##Creating function named cVal here with passing value field in it.
  delete array                       ##Deleting array here.
  num=split($field,array,"")         ##Splitting current field value passed to it and creating array.
  for(k=1;k<=num;k++){               ##Running for loop fromk=1 to till value of num here.
   if(array[k] in label){            ##Checking condition if array value with index k is present in label array then do following.
     val=label[array[k]] val         ##Creating val which has label value with index array with index k and keep concatenating its value to it.
   }
  }
  $field=val                         ##Setting current field value to val here.
  val=""                             ##Nullifying val here.
}
$NF=="change"{                       ##Checking condition if last field is change then do following.
  for(i=2;i<=(NF-1);i++){            ##Running for loop from 2nd field to 2nd last field.
    cVal(i)                          ##Calling function with passing current field number to it.
  }
}
1                                    ##1 will print current line here.
' Input_file | column -t             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: OP says *if 4th column is flagged "change"*

Comment: @oguzismail, done the change now, thank you letting know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thank you for very prompt answer - I gonna try test your solution!

Comment: @Geroge, sure I have also added detailed level explanation here in case of any queries lemme know here please.

Answer (score 2):

Kinda inefficient for this particular application since it creates the mapping array on each call to `tr()` and does the same loop in `tr()` and then again in `rev()` but figured I'd show how to write standalone `tr()` and `rev()` functions and it'll probably be fast enough for your needs anyway:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
$4 == "change" {
    for ( i=2; i<=3; i++) {
        $i = rev(tr($i,"ACGT","TGCA"))
    }
}
{ print }

function tr(instr,old,new,      outstr,pos,map) {
    for (pos=1; pos<=length(old); pos++) {
        map[substr(old,pos,1)] = substr(new,pos,1)
    }
    for (pos=1; pos<=length(instr); pos++) {
        outstr = outstr map[substr(instr,pos,1)]
    }
    return outstr
}

function rev(instr,     outstr,pos) {
    for (pos=1; pos<=length(instr); pos++) {
        outstr = substr(instr,pos,1) outstr
    }
    return outstr
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
seq     T       G       change
seq     T       A       ok
seq     G       G       change
seq     GT      AGG     change
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with `perl`:

```
$ perl -F'\t' -lane 'if($F[3] eq "change") {
                     $F[1] = (reverse $F[1] =~ tr/ATGC/TACG/r);
                     $F[2] = (reverse $F[2] =~ tr/ATGC/TACG/r) }
                     print join "\t", @F' ip.txt
seq T   G   change
seq T   A   ok
seq G   G   change
seq GT  AGG change
```

Can also use, but this is not specific to columns, will change any sequence of `ATCG` characters:

```
perl -lpe 's/\t\K[ATCG]++(?=.*\tchange$)/reverse $&=~tr|ATGC|TACG|r/ge'
```